# Two lists of same length. Get unique pairs based on one of them

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two lists of the same length. Let's say:

```
x = ['123', '456', '789', '123']
y = ['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

They are basically combinations (123-aaa, 456-aaa, 789-bbb, 123-ccc).

What I am trying to accomplish is to get the unique values and the count of unique values in list y, **BUT** only after I have removed all the pairs that have the same value in list x. So in this example I would need to delete x[3], and y[3]. And then have the counts in a dictionary:

```
{'aaa' : '2', 'bbb' : '1'}
```

I hope this is clear enough. Been banging my head against the wall for hours...

Comment: If you'd remove pairs with identical values in `x`, wouldn't that eliminate  `123: aaa` and result in `{'aaa' : 1, 'bbb' : 1}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another simple way of doing it:

```
from collections import Counter

x = ['123', '456', '789', '123']
y = ['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']

uniq = []
res = Counter()
for number, letter in zip(x, y):
    if number not in uniq:
        uniq.append(number)
        res.update(letter)

print dict(res)
```

{'aaa': 2, 'bbb': 1}

Comment: Thanks a lot - so simple... The only thing I had to change was put letter in [] as my actual list contains words and not letters and if you run the script as it is it gets recognized as a sequence of letters, not words. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Check [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) and [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). dict() replaces repeated values so you'd need to reverse your lists first.

```
In [24]: x
Out[24]: ['123', '456', '789', '123']

In [25]: y
Out[25]: ['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']

In [26]: x.reverse()

In [27]: y.reverse()

In [28]: x
Out[28]: ['123', '789', '456', '123']

In [29]: y
Out[29]: ['ccc', 'bbb', 'aaa', 'aaa']

In [30]: z=dict(zip(x,y))

In [31]: z
Out[31]: {'123': 'aaa', '456': 'aaa', '789': 'bbb'}

In [32]: from collections import Counter

In [33]: values=z.values()

In [34]: values
Out[34]: dict_values(['aaa', 'bbb', 'aaa'])

In [37]: z = Counter(values)

In [38]: z
Out[38]: Counter({'aaa': 2, 'bbb': 1})

In [39]: z['aaa']
Out[39]: 2

In [40]: z['bbb']
Out[40]: 1

In [41]: z.keys()
Out[41]: dict_keys(['bbb', 'aaa'])
```

If converting to numpy array is an option for you, check [unique](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)

```
In [39]: import numpy as np
In [40]: x = np.array(['123', '456', '789', '123'])

In [41]: y = np.array(['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'])

In [42]: x_unique, x_index = np.unique(x, return_index=True)

In [43]: x_unique
Out[43]:
array(['123', '456', '789'],
      dtype='|S3')

In [44]: x_index
Out[44]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [47]: z_unique, z_counts= np.unique(y[x_index],return_counts=True)

In [48]: z_unique
Out[48]:
array(['aaa', 'bbb'],
      dtype='|S3')

In [49]: z_counts
Out[49]: array([2, 1])

In [50]: z = dict(zip(z_unique, z_counts))

In [51]: z
Out[51]: {'aaa': 2, 'bbb': 1}
```